# Symfony form, saving filtration through pagination

Tags: forms, symfony, pagination

I use filtration form and pagination on same page to display great number of objects.
If i use POST form, after going through pagination filtration resets. If i use GET form filtration works, but URL is not clear and even have token.

Something like this: 
?form[date_from][year]=&form[date_from][month]=&form[date_from][day]=&form[date_to][year]=&form[date_to][month]=&form[date_to][day]=&form[email]=email&form[submit]=&form[_token]=Nk0prilVJiROZaQQKvCt-hRfnKdh0IdDOWOIer

Is any way to make url more clear, hide token and unused parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i find no solution and write service for handling form filtration data in sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Save filtration: use an array in controller:

```
$filter_array=[];
if ($search_form->isSubmitted() && $search_form->isValid()) {
    $search_form->getData();
    //save post/get form data without empty fields
    $filter_array[$search_form->getName()]=array_filter(
        $request->get($search_form->getName()),
        function($value) { return $value !== ''; }); 
        //... etc
}
```

Solution 1- make forms in your page links and add hidden fields with $filter_array

Solution 2- in page links use a script to add a hidden form field with page number and submit the form, simple but the form could be modified before click.

Solution 3- Put the paginator navigation and search results in a div,  use jquery.load() for all actions (send form, page links, $( document ).ready() ...). The url will look like domain/page/#page_1:

```
{% for i in range(1, paginator.getTotalPages()) %}
    <li {% if paginator.getPage() == i  %} class="active"{%endif%}>
    <a href="#page_{{i}}" onClick="
        $('{{selector}}').load('{{ paginationPath }}',
        {{filter_array|merge({page: i,})|json_encode()}});"
        href="#page_{{i}}">{{ i }}</a>
        </li>
{%endfor%}
```